# How to call Java method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, javabeans, onload

I am creating web page using JSF 2.0.

What I want to do is, call one method `setLastVisitedPage` that I have in bean `MyBean` when everypage loads.

I can do this by simply writing

```
<h:body onLoad="#{MyBean.setLastVisitedPage()}"
```

however I would have to write in all pages and already there are 30-40 pages created. :(

In page as I have common heading, I have created one file called `commonPage.xhtml`. I was thinking to include that file here.

So I added below in `commonPage.xhtml` so that whenever any page is loaded, `myScript.js` gets called and I get alert as "i m here".

```
<h:outputScript name="js/myScript.js" target="head" />
```

and `myScript.js` has

```
onload = alert("i m here");
```

Whenever I open any new page, I am getting alert as "i m here".

***Now my question is how can I add `#{MyBean.setLastVisitedPage()}` in javascript so that `setLastVisitedPage()` get called for every page?***

Is there any alternative way? May be I am thinking in wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JSF you better use the *PreRenderViewEvent* , like this

```
 <f:metadata>
     <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{MyBean.putLastVisitedPage}"/>
 </f:metadata>


public void putLastVisitedPage(ComponentSystemEvent event){
}
```

take a look here [JSF 2 PreRenderViewEvent Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/)

Comment: let me try... If it looks beautiful, I will let you know :)

Comment: getting exception as `javax.faces.FacesException: Service Tracker has not been initialized`

Comment: don't know that was for something else... after re-compiling all working smoothly.. Thanks for help again...

Comment: Could you please look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701143/calling-bean-method-on-image-onclick-event)