# calling bean method on image onClick event

Tags: html, image, jsp, jsf-2, onclick

I have image and would like to call a method that is store in bean. I was thinking of

```
<h:graphicImage value="DisplayImage?id=1&amp;stuff=photo&amp;mainID=main" 
 onclick="
          alert('clicked me 1');
          #{PersonalInformationDataBean.doSaveImage()};
          alert('clicked me 2');
         " styleClass="modal"/>
```

I was expecting `#{PersonalInformationDataBean.doSaveImage()};` to work, however this is not working. I am only getting alert as `clicked me 1`

Any idea how to get this done?

### Update 1

Forget to update that I am doing this in **JSP Page**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how bout something like this

```
<h:graphicImage value="DisplayImage?id=1&amp;stuff=photo&amp;mainID=main" 
 onclick="$('#myFormID\\:myButtonID').click();" styleClass="modal"/>
<h:commandButton id="myButtonID" action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.doSaveImage()}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax/>
</h:commandButton>
```

you might have to play a bit with the jquery selector `$('#myFormID\\:myButtonID')` or `$('#myButtonID')`

OR

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:ajax event="action" listener="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.doSaveImage()}"/>
    <h:graphicImage value="DisplayImage?id=1&amp;stuff=photo&amp;mainID=main" 
    styleClass="modal"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel... I will take a look and let you know...

Comment: forget to update that I am doing this in JSP page and f:ajax is not working there...

Comment: there are no JSP in JSF2... if you are using JSF2 move on to facelets... read about it JSP is obsolete in JSF2...

Comment: I am using `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>` in JSP page. I am able to use <f:ajax in jsf pages however not in JSP. Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: You must have a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>`

Comment: even <h:head> is not allowing in JSP...

Comment: well then google a bit about using f:ajax in jsp with jsf2 , dunno...

Comment: ok... I will check and let you know...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that  `#{PersonalInformationDataBean.doSaveImage()}; is a function which you've defined in your server and is not a javascript object method. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem here is you're trying to access server side methods from client side javascript. Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, you need some intermediate technology to access those methods.

DWR is a powerful tool that will allow you to achieve *exactly* this. Check out http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/index.html .I've used this countless times and it never fails.

Comment: While you're right about the concrete cause of OP's fail, I disagree using DWR for this. JSF has its own tags and facilities to achieve the desired functional requirement.

Comment: thanks... any link from where I can get the code (for idea how it is working)

Comment: @BalusC : Could you please tell me the same...

Comment: @BalusC : Can you elaborate on that? Even I'm curious to know the solution which you have in mind. Are you talking about calling JSF Handler functions?